# Very slow to load standard text message view controller

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have some simple code that loads the standard text message controller.

It is very slow to present the view for the first time. Once it is loaded the first time subsequent loading it again does not take long. Is there anything I can do to speed things up ?

```
- (IBAction)actionSMS:(id)sender {

MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    controller.body = self.MessageDetail.text;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way of solving this would be preloading `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

It depends how your app is organised but you could make `controller` a `property` of appropriate `viewcontroller` (or maybe `appDelegate`, some will argue with that).

So you would call:

```
self.controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

somewhere in `viewDidLoad` or `applicationDidFinishWithLaunching`...

You then simply present the `controller` when needed.

NOTE: this is not exactly a memory-friendly approach.

Comment: Cheers Thanks ... yes sorted by loading in the delegate.... now going to have a load banner...